# How to pass special characters as string argument using structopt?

Tags: rust, structopt

I have a command line to search a word inside a file. I'm using StructOpt to get the word that the user wants to search.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
pub struct Command {
    pub word_to_search: Option<String>,
}
```

The problem comes when you write something like `command -a`. I know that the library is trying to do something with `-a` and there is no `-a` in the `struct`, so I tried: `command "-a"` but it displays:

`error: Found argument '-a' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`

Is there a way to pass special characters like `-a` and retrieve the information (`-a`) using StructOpt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change anything, you only have to call the command using `command -- -a`. The double dash is used to indicate that it's the end of options and in this case the rest is the word that the user is looking for.