# Rust structopt fails to get argument value starting with -

Tags: rust, structopt

I have a program that runs a custom command, lets say it is called `cmd`, and the program can take custom arguments for that command. So, using `structopt` crate I can created a `struct` that looks like the following:

```rust
#[derive(StructOpt)]
struct Args {
    #[structopt(short, long)
    custom: String
}
```

So, when running the program with the following example:

```bash
cargo run -- -c "-e env"
```

`-e env` is an argument for the `cmd` command that will be run as a child process.

But, the program fails with the following error:

```
error: Found argument '-e env' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471608/how-to-pass-special-characters-as-string-argument-using-structopt) answer, but it is not the same case as mine.

What I tried is the following:

- **Custom parser**: Parse the string from `&str` back into `String`

```rust
fn parse_custom_command(custom: &str) -> Result<String, ParseCharError> {
    custom.split_whitespace().collect()
}

#[derive(StructOpt)]
struct Args {
    #[structopt(short, long, parse(try_from_str = parse_custom_command)]
    custom: String
}
```

But, I get the same error.

I know that is hard to tell the parser that `-e` is not an option in the struct, I think it needs to know at lease one of two:

- `-t` is the last argument, so take whatever is after
- Take everything between `"` of the `-t` argument

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Just FYI, the functionality of structopt has now been folded into the clap crate, so you should use that instead for new projects.

Comment: [`clap` supports this with `#[arg(short, long, allow_hyphen_values = true)]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61df5b101c90c80bcdf07eb6f2a8c49a)

Comment: I did not know about `clap` is now the main crate, I tested `allow_hyphen_values` and it worked, you can post it as an answer and I will check it as correct one.